How to cover this toe-kick frame that I built to match this cabinet window bench I built?
I'm building this window bench using some wall cabinets and raised it about 1.5" off the ground using wood frame on the bottom. I want to have it match the color of the cabinet and wasn’t sure the best path.
Read about using thin plywood but couldn’t find smaller strips. Also thought about painting it.
What is the easiest way to cover the toe kick to match the white cabinet color?

Can also think about using an accent colour, instead of using the same colour.

The other common solution is to paint it black. It won't match, but people will tend not to notice it; a shadow is expected at the base of objects. You may or may not like the resulting look when the door is opened.

The easiest way to cover is with a toe kick panel in the same color as the cabinets.  Most all cabinet manufacturers supply toe kick painted to match the cabinets.
Since you opted to make the rise only 1 1/2 inches you will need to rip the standard 4 inch size down to the 1 1/2" you need. Then a few dabs of construction adhesive and a few finish nails and it's done.
